# Apache Flink + Spring Boot Actuator

Tags: spring-boot, apache-flink, flink-streaming, spring-boot-actuator

I'm writing an Apache Flink 1.15 streaming application with Spring Boot 2.7.x. I use maven shade plugin to package the application as a fat Jar.
My pom.xml looks very similar to [this](https://github.com/btleedev/Flink-Streaming-Spring-Boot/blob/master/pom.xml) by btleedev.

Worth mentioning these two dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

This is the main class

```
@SpringbootApplication
public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
}
```

Because Spring Boot, I'm able to define Flink execution environment as bean:

```
@Configuration
public class FlinkConfig {
  @Bean
  public StreamExecutionEnvironment executionEnvironment() {
    return StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
  }
}
```

Finally, this is the class where Flink job is built and executed:

```
@Component
public class MyJob {
  @Autowired
  private StreamExecutionEnvironment environment;

  public void buildJob() {
    DataStream stream = environment.fromSource(...);
    //job streaming logic
    ...

    //execute job
    environment.execute();
  }
}
```

I'm able to run the application within the IDE (IntelliJ), simply launching the main class.
Everything seems ok: I see Flink JobManager startup logs initializing and scheduling job task, Spring logs indicating that the Spring Application is started on Tomcat on 8080 port.
Finally I see my job execution logs.

What I don't see are logs by Spring Boot actuator, i.e:

```
Exposing 1 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
```

In fact `http://localhost:8080/actuator/health` is not exposed.

Why actuator is not working? Can you help me please?

---

EDIT:
I just noticed that running the job by submitting the Jar to an application cluster using the command:

```
standalone-job.sh start --job-classname my.flink.job.Application
```

the application crashes with the logs

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Web application could not be started as there was no org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.ServletWebServerFactory bean defined in the context.
```

This happens only if I add the actuator dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

For completeness this is the  section of the pom.xml file

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${target.java.version}</source>
                    <target>${target.java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Run shade goal on package phase -->
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactSet>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-shaded-force-shading</exclude>
                                    <exclude>com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305</exclude>
                                    <exclude>ch.qos.logback:*</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.slf4j:*</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.logging.log4j:*</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </artifactSet>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <!-- Do not copy the signatures in the META-INF folder.
                                    Otherwise, this might cause SecurityExceptions when using the JAR. -->
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/spring.tooling</resource>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer implementation="org.springframework.boot.maven.PropertiesMergingResourceTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/spring.factories</resource>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>my.flink.job.Application</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        ...
    <plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: did this run successfully in a cluster ? with spring boot singletons exchanged between task-managers

Comment: It can be another issue if beans are not serializable.